# How do I split or tokenize a string only when 2 delimiters are present together (adjacent to each other)

Tags: java, split, delimiter, stringtokenizer

I am reading in lines,and I need to split each line when the delimiter `;` (semicolon + space) is present. Each line is as follows: s1; s2 s3; s4. I want to split this line where `;` (semicolon + space) exists. I want to split only where semicolon and space are adjacent to each other, where a space follows a semicolon.

How would I do this using StringTokenizer?

I have already tried split("; ") but this splits the String at every occurrence of a space.

I have also tried new StringTokenizer(strLine,"\s*;\s+"), but this splits at every occurrence of 's'.

```
String[] parsedStr = inputString.split(...);

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(...);
```

I expect the output to be:

```
("s1","s2 s3","s4") Every token should be an element within this array.
```

NOT

```
("s1"," s2 s3"," s4")
```

NOR

```
("s1","s2","s3","s4")
```

Comment: just use StringTokenizer

Comment: Are you sure? In my experience `inputString.split("; ")` works really well.

Comment: Using StringTokenizer is giving me the same issue.

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete program. My guess is that the bug is not in the `String.split` call but somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with `"\\s*;\\s+"`. It will remove any initial or trailing spaces. Also requires ';' to be followed with at least 1 space.

```java
        String inputString = "s1; s2 s3; s4;s5";
        String[] parsedStr = inputString.split("\\s*;\\s+");

        System.out.print(Arrays.asList(parsedStr)); // ["s1", "s2 s3", "s4;s5"]
```

**Edit:**

If you need to split by semicolon and exact one space and keep the other spaces, you can modify the above solution as follows:

```java
        String inputString = "s1; s2 s3; s4;s5; s6;  s7;";
        String[] parsedStr = inputString.split(";\\s{1}");

        System.out.print(Arrays.asList(parsedStr)); // ["s1", "s2 s3", "s4;s5", "s6", " s7;"]
```

Comment: I tried the code, but get "s4" and "s5" as two strings, not "s4;s5"

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. You need \\s+ (at least one space)  instead of \\s* (0 or more) after ';'

Comment: Yes, now "s4;s5" shows.
but if the input is "s1;  s2 s3; s4;s5";( two space in front of s2), then other issue raises.
maybe this is not a good direction for solving the problem : - )

Comment: no, I mean when there are two spaces in front of "s2 s3", then the result should be " s2 s3" ( with one space in front of s2). but \\s* removes all the spaces.

Comment: Then you should specify the exact number of the trailing spaces, like that ";\\s{1}". I will update my answer.

Comment: I tried this using a StringTokenizer, st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, "\\s*;\\s+"); but it gives me a new issue, spliting at every occurrence of "s".

Answer (score 0):

As per your previous question, the solution would be as below :

```
   public class Split {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = "s1; s2 s3; s4;s5";
        String[] parsedStr = inputString.split("; | |;");
        System.out.print(Arrays.asList(parsedStr));
    } }
```

Since, you have edited your problem statement, the solution will be simple like :

```
inputString.split("; ");
```

Comment: This still splits at every occurrence of space.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String [] args){
 java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner
                        ("s1; s2 s3; s4").useDelimiter("\\s*; \\s*");

       while(input.hasNext())
       {
       System.out.print(input.next()+",");
       }
  input.close();
}
```

Comment: This code will also split on a semicolon _without_ a trailing space.

Comment: i got that part , but in the expected output there is a space btw s2 and s3

Comment: Yep, that's _one example_, and the specification says multiple times: the delimiter is _exactly_ semicolon-space.